# Why is setting the selection in WPF datagrid not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, selectedindex

I have problem on setting the selection on DataGrid. I save the SelectedIndex, but when I want to set it back after some refresh, it doesn't seem to work.

```
int index = dgrid.SelectedIndex;
//some code including resresh of the DG
dgrid.SelectedIndex = index;
```

I have some code which triggers on SelectionChanged, which actually fires.

```
private void dgrid_selection_change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string ID = 
(dgrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(dgrid.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text;

//some code that shall execute...
```

When I try to get some data from it, the selection is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't figure out why it is not working, but found a solution.
Just replaced

```
string ID = (dgrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(dgrid.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text;
```

to

```
string ID= (dgrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["ID"].ToString();
```

and it works.

Comment: your dgrid.SelectedItem was not NULL?

Comment: EDIT: SelectedItem wasn't null.

Comment: If selected item is null how can you cast to DataRowView, Just out of curiosity

Comment: Just tried it 1 more time, the dgrid.SelectedItem looks good.